# Failed to load MBeanServerBuilder : VisualVM

Tags: java, jboss, visualvm

When the VisualVM starts, the console shows error log

```
javax.management.JMRuntimeException: Failed to load MBeanServerBuilder class org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerBuilderImpl: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerBuilderImpl
```

But, jboss-jmx.jar exists inside my Jboss 4 and MBeanServerBuilderImpl class is included in the jar. Anyway to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

all you need is :
-Djboss.platform.mbeanserver=true

1/  you can edit the preferences like :

[edit the preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtRvJ.png)

2/  or  you can edit the "run.bat" file under the JBoss_home

[edit the run.bat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnrsl.png)